# jQuery - hide calendar events

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I have a WordPress site with the Events Manager and WP FullCalendar plugins on a development site here: [https://kph.naturallylewes.co.uk/events/]

I can target other page elements and use addClass() without issue but am not able to target specific events in the calendar.

I'd like to target the Booking Request events that exist before the current date and hide them. The links have a background-color etc set with inline css but I can't target the elements to apply changes. I've tried using jQuery to select links based on the text string but still no luck. In fact, I can't seem to target ANY of the elements within the WP FullCalendar form. (Not even the H2 for the month.)

I can add classes all the way up to the form wrapper but other script events seem to prevent further success.

An example of the code I have been testing is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.wpfc-calendar-wrapper').addClass('cal-wrap'); // WORKS!
  jQuery('.wpfc-calendar-wrapper form').addClass('cal-form'); //WORKS!
  jQuery('.wpfc-calendar-wrapper form .fc-toolbar').addClass('cal-toolbar'); //NOT WORKING!
  jQuery('.fc-view-container a span.fc-title:contains("Booking Request")').addClass('hidden'); //NOT WORKING
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: If you want to hide elements based on their text content, try something like this:
jQuery('.fc-view-container a span.fc-title:contains("Fit")').closest('a').hide(). This way you can hide all links containing "Fit".

Comment: Hi David, noted - thanks. Roman, thanks for your reply. This works on other pages elements where I have tested it but not inside the calendar. I used this: 
jQuery('.fc-view-container a span.fc-title:contains("Booking Request")').closest('a').addClass('hidden');

Comment: I have also tried using the location.pathname which works on the footer link which goes to the same place, but it is not working in the calendar:
`jQuery(function() {
  var url = location.pathname; // returns the URL path
  if("url:contains('booking-request')") {
    jQuery('.fc-event-container').addClass('hidden');
  }
});

jQuery(function() {
  var urli = location.pathname; // returns the URL path
  if("urli:contains('booking-request')") {
    jQuery('.ast-nav-menu a').addClass('hidden');
  }
});`

Comment: If you want to check for specific string in the URL, you should use `if (url.indexOf('booking-request') !== -1 ){ ... }`, where `url = location.pathname`.

Comment: Thanks - I tested that in the footer and it didn't work. I tested this which turned the Book the Hall and Bookings & Events links red:
`jQuery('.ast-nav-menu a:contains("Book")').css('color', 'red');`
I changed the string to "Hall" and got the first link turning red as expected so went back to trying in the calendar. 
Still no luck. I'm wondering if the WP FullCalendar plugin using the themeroller is the problem?

Comment: Rather than adding disconnected snipets of code to these comments, it would generally be a lot easier for people to answer if you provide a [mre] of the issue within your post. You can [edit] it anytime. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for slow response - been unwell. Post updated.

Comment: Hi Roman and all, does my post edit help?